# Multiple compiled libraries in one Function App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

is it possible to have more than one compiled library in one Function App?
I'm wondering with "Function Proxies" if that would still be applicable with a compiled C# library?! 
Or is there `1 Function App == 1 compiled library` ?
Cheers
David

Comment: Yeah, I figured I needed to add a second "function directory" with another `function.json`.
Thing is, I'm not sure what the best practice here is supposed to be:
- add a new class to the same `run.cs` or 
- add a new project to the same solution?

I tried the latter but couldn't get it working. It wouldn't build the second library on KUDU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple C# libraries per function app, just use a different value for "scriptFile" and "entryPoint".

The best way to do this would be to have 2 class library projects and one Web project for deployment.

Example layout:

- FirstClassLibrary
- SecondClassLibrary
- WebProject: references class libraries above and contains function.json files

FirstFunc/function.json would contain:

`"scriptFile": "..\\bin\\First.dll",
 "entryPoint": "Namespace.MyFunction"`

Second/function.json would contain:

`"scriptFile": "..\\bin\\Second.dll",
 "entryPoint": "Namespace.MyOtherGreatFunction"`

To check the Kudu build, try msbuild for the solution from the command line. If that works, Kudu should also work.

Comment: Cool, thanks Donna. Guess I need to also up my Visual Studio skills to get it to build multiple libraries. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there can only be one compiled C# library per Function app.
So, only one `.dll`. 
I added a new class to the existing `run.cs` and a new folder containing a `function.json` referencing that new class as the entry point.
This ended up building one `.dll` on Azure Function with two separate functions.
I guess for me, not being the bestest of the best in C# yet, this seems okay, but not sure if that's really the way to go.
Appreciate any feedback. This here is now my repo: https://github.com/davidobrien1985/o365_functions